# can't install tensorflow library

Tags: windows, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install TensorFlow in windows.

*Using pip command:*

```sh
pip install tensorflow
```

*But I'm getting this error message:*

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\naray\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorflow_estimator\\python\\estimator\\canned\\linear_optimizer\\python\\utils\\__pycache__\\sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-38.pyc'
```

Can someone help me solve this error?

Comment: Installing Tensorflow directly is not a good practice, I would recommend installing TensorFlow in an environment like [conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/). Maybe watch this [video](https://youtu.be/KZFn0dvPZUQ).

Comment: have you checked, either the directory in your cache accessible?